# SQL Server - Dynamic Pivot Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I've been reading the various examples on this board but haven't been able to whip up a dynamic pivot query to fit my code. Any help would be appreciated!

I have two tables

AuxDef

```
Fieldnumber  Fieldlabel
------------------------
1            Buyer
2            Size Range
3            Source
4            Country
5            Vendor
ect...       ect...
```

AuxFields

```
PageID   FieldNumber   TextValue
-----------------------------------
1        1             Sam
1        2             S-L
1        3             Domestic
1        4             Canada
2        1             Kyla
2        3             Import
2        5             VendorName
2        6             Off-Shore
2        7             Fit 1
2        8             Yes
4        1             Sara
4        3             Import
4        4             China
ect..    ect..         ect..
```

What I would like to do is create a dynamic pivot that joins the two tables by fieldnumber and uses the fieldlabels as the column headers after pageid. It would look similar to this.

```
PageID   Buyer     Size Range   Source     Country   Vendor      Type       Status   Exclusive   ect..
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        Sam       S-L          Domestic   Canada 
2        Kyla                   Import              VendorName  Off-Shore   Fit 1    Yes
4        Sara                   Import     China
```

I've tried examples on this site but I keep running into errors either when I replace the fields with my own or in the actual column generation.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried and what was the error it returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a dynamic pivot (credit to [@bluefeet's answer here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404455/1821329)  something like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.FieldLabel) 
            FROM auxdef c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT PageID, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
             select 
                 PageId,
                 FieldLabel,
                 TextValue
            from AuxFields af
            inner join auxdef ad on af.FieldNumber = ad.FieldNumber
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(TextValue)
                for FieldLabel in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query);
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88d9c/6/0)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way

[sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92780/1)

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = 'select af.pageId'

select @sql = @sql + ', max(case when ad.fieldLabel = ''' + ad.fieldLabel + ''' then af.textValue end) as [' + ad.fieldLabel + ']' + char(13)
from auxDef ad

select @sql = @sql + 'from auxDef ad' + char(13)
+ 'inner join auxFields af on af.fieldNumber = ad.fieldNumber' + char(13)
+ 'group by af.pageId'

exec(@sql)
```